# Не могу подключить картинку, пишет ошибку net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Полеэтеленовая пленка</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="div-1">
        <div class="Menu">

        </div>
        <div class="Buy">

        </div>
        <div class="image">
            <img  class="plenka" src="assets\img\plenka.jpg">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
Есть еще основной код могу скинуть
```

Comment: Значит, путь неверно указан

Comment: Попробуйте так: `src=".\assets\img\plenka.jpg"`, или так `src="./assets/img/plenka.jpg"`

Comment: Попробуйте в src прописать путь к любой другой картинке, которая лежит в интернете, например: https://im0-tub-ru.yandex.net/i?id=67655f2b20e73bfa6b1a03e58f736d47-l&n=13 Если отработает, значит, всё-таки дело именно в пути